# Queries are getting queued when multiple user trying to access Database(Same table) db2 warehouse on cloud

Tags: db2, queued-connection

Queries are getting queued when multiple user trying to access Database(Same table) db2 warehouse on cloud.
We are using DB2 Warehouse on cloud and our Analytical report tool is Dundas and Cognos. When multiple user using same Dashboard/report that time all the sqls getting queued and user are not getting response. User does not have option customized backed sqls which generate by report tool.
Is there any way we tune the parameter so that we can avoid sqls are geeting queued?

Comment: Your question is not clear and missing information. What service plan are you using, what queries, how are the queries submitted?

Comment: 1) For Cognos, what is your cursor isolation level? look at the connection definition to the datasource, try read uncommitted (aka dirty read)  2) can you check if there is a record lock?  try WRKOBJLCK